# Voltage divider with offset

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, dc-offset

I am trying to build a voltage divider with an offset. I have an input signal of 10 Vpk and I want it to have a DC offset of +1.65 V. The problem is that I don't have a DC source of 1.65 V, but I do have 3.3 V (2x 1.65). I tried to solve this with a resistor, but then I realized there was no current flowing from the source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fphaSj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSEQKb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this:

[image]